# How to send a HttpRequest using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http, servlets, jax-rs

I have a proxy server (JAX-RS) and I want to forward some request to an other server.
I can do that, with getting the original Request, get all headers and data from it, and one-by-one set the HttpURLConnection, but it's not efficient I think.

Is there a way to

- just **forward** the request

OR

- **"clone" the request**, send it to the other server, and then send back the client the response

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with RequestDispatcher.forward(request) or sendredirect() methods?

Comment: The RequestDispatcher.forward(request) is (as I know) no good for forwarding to an other server (just in the same servlet context)
The sendRedirect is (as I know) sends back a 301 HTTP response, with a LOCATION header, which is not a forward